# How to seed in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to seed my DB following the instructions on http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }

}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(array('email' => 'foo@bar.com'));
    }

}
```

I'm a bit confused by this. What is `User` in `User::create(array('email' => 'foo@bar.com'));`?

Comment: `E_NOT_WORKING` is not a know PHP error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The create method inserts a record in the database (Seeding is a way of pre-populating the database).

It basically invokes the Model named `User` and uses the `Create()` method in a **static** manner by passing an array and returns an instance of the model representing the user entity with the passed details.

Comment: So I need to create a model first. Do I just make the file or is there a composer/artisan way to get started? I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: The User model is included in Laravel by default. You can create your own model manually, or use artisan tool like the L4 generators: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators